# How to i make the Ball stop continue rolling after adding force to it in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So my problem is the Player (A ball) continues rolling after adding force from left or right. How do I make it stop at the point it reaches without continue rolling?

```
if (Input.GetKey("d"))
{                                   
    rb.AddForce(0, 0, -sideWaysForce * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}

if (Input.GetKey("a"))
{  
    rb.AddForce(0, 0, sideWaysForce * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
```

Right now after adding force the ball continues rolling for an x time (depends on the amount of the force added to the player)

Comment: If possible, some more information would be great.  What is your intended functionality?  Do you want it to just slowly roll to a stop?  Or to you want it to bounce off a barrier, stop at a pre-determined point, or some other kind of functionality?  They would all be done different ways, so if you could clarify this it would really help!

Answer (score 1):

You can set isKinematic to true when you need it to stop instantly.  For example, if you wanted the ball to stop instantly when the player stopped pressing the D key, you could do something like:

```
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D)) {
    rb.isKinematic = true;
}
```

Doing this will effectively remove the Rigidbody from physics calculations so you need to make sure that you set `rb.isKinematic = false` before/when you want to start using it as a physics object again (i.e. before you try to call AddForce on it or use it in a collision).

See [the Unity documentation on isKinematic for more information](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html).

There are other ways to do this such as applying an opposite force to the Rigidbody's current velocity or manipulating angular drag or modifying surface friction.  The most suitable approach depends on how you envision "stopping" the ball.

Answer (score 0):

Set Rigidbody velocity and angularVelocity to Zero

Example

```
rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
```